# Is it possible to generically sort in linear time?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to solve a problem in O(n) time where, given two forward iterators to the front of a container and the back of a container, I want to remove all elements in the container that don't appear at least < this number > of times.  For example, given a vector of strings such as ("john", "hello", "one", "yes", "hello", "one") and I wanted to remove all elements that appear less than 2 times, my final vector would then contain just ("hello", "one").

I was thinking that if I could generically sort in O(n) time I can accomplish this result (in O(n) time), but I'm having a hard time doing that with strings, ints, chars, or whatever else may be used (generically).  Am I thinking about this correctly, or is there a simpler way to solve the problem?

Comment: Comparison sorts are the most common, and cannot be done in O(N) time.  However, if you know details about your data, some O(1) sorts can be done.  Actually, I'd recommend using a `std::unordered_map` and mapping strings to counts, rather than sorting the data.

Comment: OP says nothing about comparison sort... I am surprised no one has brought up any non-comparison sorting algorithms that are O(n).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are not actually sorting but removing elements.

1). Store each word into a hashset.
2).  Lookup and only add if not in hashset.

Comment: Note that a hashset is called `unordered_map` in the STL.

Comment: Of course, that still won't be quite order N, since a hashset is log(N) in the limit.

Comment: @HotLicks: well, actually, O(N) is the limit. A hashset *typically* performs O(1) amortized over all operations.

Comment: @SrikantKrishna: Add `@...` to your comments so it's clear who you're replying to,

Comment: @nneonneo I'm a Gen-Xer new to this. Thanks.

Comment: The speed of the hash is a function of the max size of the set, generally adhering to log(N).  (This is the dirty little secret of most complexity statements -- lots of log(N) operations are buried in the "constants".)

Comment: Actually, there is no requirement on how the unordered map is implemented.  You choose:  BST, hashset, (lol) linked list.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no. Comparison based sorting takes `O(n log n)` time. (This can be formally proved.) If you know something about your input (e.g. the input is distributed uniformly at random within a known range) then you can use well known algorithms such as bucket sort or radix sort in `O(n)` time. Contrary to @Mooing Duck, there is no such thing as sorting in `O(1)` time (this should be obvious -- you must visit each element at least once for any sorting algorithm).

However, as several other posters have noted, your problem does not require a sorting algorithm ...

Comment: +1 (it would be fantastic to get a reference for the formal proof, though).

Comment: @jogojapan i posted a link to a pdf of a semi-formal proof here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023106/re-ordering-an-array-so-it-is-grouped-by-identical-elements/14027086#14027086

Comment: If you have a copy of "Introduction to Algorithms" (aka CLRS) read chapter 8.1. If you are not fortunate enough to have a copy, here is a pdf that gives the gist:  http://www.bowdoin.edu/~ltoma/teaching/cs231/fall07/Lectures/sortLB.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to sort

1) Populate `std::unordered_map<string,vector<int>> indexOfStrings;` - O(N)

2) For each `string` whose `vector size() < 2`, delete element - O(number of deletions) <= O(N)

`indexOfStrings` - stores the index of each occurance of the string. This allows for quick deletion from vector without the need for a search.

Comment: Why `vector<int>`? Just make a plain counter.

Comment: @nneonneo I was actually storing the indices to the elements to faciliate fast deletion. But counter and regeneration of the vector is another option

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a sort, you just need an `unordered_map`:

```
unordered_map<string, int> counter;
vector<string> newvec;
for(string &s : v) {
    if((++counter[s]) == 2) {
        newvec.push_back(s);
    }
}
```

Note that this is C++11 code. (Thanks @jogojapan for the code improvement suggestion).